# How to get a first word of from a Qstring

Tags: qt, qstring, qregexp

I want to get first word of a `Qstring`.

For example `String1 = "Read from file1"`. I want to extract `string2 = "Read"`.
I want to extract substring based on whitespace.

If I encounter a first whitespace in my `string1`, I need that part of `string1` to `string2`.

Comment: You should provide some code, how you try to solve your problem.

Answer (score 6):

Use the split function of `QString` in this way:

```
QString firstWord = string1.split(" ").at(0);
```

If there is no whitespace in the string, the whole string will be returned.

Comment: You’d better check if it’s not empty before calling at(0)

Comment: In the docs it says that if there is no occurrence, the split() returns a single-element list containing the string itself. So it will always return at least a one element list.

Comment: Indeed, it even does that when splitting a null string.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`QString::split`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#split) if you want to use all the parts, or [`QString::section`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#section) if you just want to grab the first word.

For example, the most basic syntax is:

```
QString str = "Do re mi";
QString firstWord = str.section(" ", 0, 0);
// firstWord = "Do"
```

If you need to handle all kinds of weird whitespace, you can use [the regex version](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#section-3) of the functions:

```
QString str = "\tDo    re\nmi"; // tabs and newlines and spaces, oh my!
QString firstWord = str.section(QRegExp("\\s+"), 0, 0, 
    QString::SectionSkipEmpty);
// firstWord = "Do"
```

Comment: "If end is not specified, all fields from position start to the end of the string are included", so it has to be `firstWord = str.section(" ", 0, 0);`, right?

Comment: @user1712200 Seems so. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
QString s("Read from file1");
QString subStr = s.section(" ", 0, 0, QString::SectionSkipEmpty);
```

This will work correctly in case of such strings too:

> "   Read    from file1   "